# Using proc_open() to run C executable in PHP

Tags: php, c, exec, popen, proc-open

I am sorry (again) if you find this question noob. But I am really having a problem on **proc_open**.

I have a **C file** and I want to run it using `proc_open()` and read the input from a textfile. I was able to fetch and feed the input to the executable. The problem is that I just hardcoded the `array of fetched strings`.

**PHP code fragments:**

```
        $descriptorspec = array(
            0 => array("pipe", "r"), 
            1 => array("pipe", "w"),  
            2 => array("file", "error.log", "a") 
        );

        $process = proc_open('C:/xampp/htdocs/ci_user/add2', $descriptorspec, $pipes);
        sleep(1);

        if (is_resource($process)) {

        //Read input.txt by line and store it in an array
        $input = file('C:/xampp/htdocs/ci_user/input.txt');

        //Feed the input (hardcoded)
        fwrite($pipes[0], "$input[0] $input[1]");

        fclose($pipes[0]);

        while ($s = fgets($pipes[1])) {
            print $s."</br>";
            flush();
        }
         fclose($pipes[1]); 


        }
```

**add2.c**

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(void) {
      int first, second;

      printf("Enter two integers > ");
      scanf("%d", &first);
        scanf("%d", &second);
      printf("The two numbers are: %d  %d\n", first, second);
      printf("Output: %d\n", first+second);
    }
```

**streams on pipes[1] ( the printf's)**

```
Enter two integers > The two numbers are: 8 2 
Output: 10
```

**Question:** Is there a "**dynamic way**" on how the "**$input**" elements will be laid out as input on

```
            fwrite($pipes[0], "$input[0] $input[1]");
```

Or is there a more convenient way to get inputs from a file and feed it whenever there is `scanf` in the C executable that was ran by the `proc_open()`.

(Btw, for those having trouble in `proc_open()`, especially for the starters like myself, I hope my codes help you somehow. This is my first time to make it run after few attempts so my codes are simple.)

And for the Pro's, please help meeeee. :( THANK YOU!

Comment: No problem glad you got your answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about?

```
fwrite($pipes[0],implode(" ",$input));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Answer (score 1):

Use [stream_select](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-select.php):

```
do {
    $r = array($descriptorspec[1], $descriptorspec[2]);
    $w = array($descriptorspec[0]);
    $ret = stream_select($r, $w, $e, null);
    foreach($r as $s) {
      if($s === $descriptorspec[1]) {
        // read from stdout here
      } elseif($s === $descriptorspec[2]) {
        // read from stderr here
      }
    }
    foreach($w as $s) {
      if($s === $descriptorspec[0]) {
        // write to stdin here
      }
    }
  } while($ret);
```

Comment: Thanks @Marek! Will definitely try this one!